# Technology similar to Server Side Include, but pre-generated

Tags: html, template-engine, ssi

I'm taking over development of a small website that is entirely static html currently.  I'm trying to DRY it up where I can, since there's a lot of repeated HTML.  I want to use something similar to server side includes.

However, I'm hesitant to use SSI because all my pages are completely static--I really don't have any need to wait until a request to have my webserver generate the html.  I'm looking for a simple program to generate static html from a template via command line, then serve these generated static pages to visitors.

I looked at something like [HAML](http://haml.info/), but that would require me to rewrite all the existing pages on the site.

Comment: If the template and substitutions are simple enough, or if you can make it simple enough, consider just `sed` or build-tool (Ant, Gradle, etc) based substitution. Otherwise, if your HTML's are XHTML, XSLT probably is a choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question in case any others might come across the same issue.

I ended up using [jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/), which is a ruby-powered static site generator.

I chose jekyll mainly [because it is built in to Github Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-as-a-static-site-generator-with-github-pages/), meaning that my static site will be able to take advantage of Github's free hosting options.